# Yii validation of a specific field

Tags: php, yii

problem defenition

i have one model called 'user.php'
i have some validation rules on the same as follows
i am now going to create a password reset form
in that form i have a text box name email (same email used in user model)
in password reset form i would like to check wheather this user is a registered one if it a registered one will send the password reset link

I DONT KNOW HOW TO VAIDATE THIS EMAIL FIELD , ANY HELP HIGHLY APPRECIABLE AS I AM NEW IN YII

user.php

```
    class Users extends CActiveRecord
{
public $cpassword;
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
public function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('email, password, user_type , cpassword','required'),
            array('email', 'length', 'max'=>200),
                        array('email', 'unique'),
                        array('email', 'email'),
            array('password', 'length', 'max'=>300),
                        array('cpassword', 'length', 'max'=>300),
            array('user_type', 'length', 'max'=>5),
                        array('cpassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'),

            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, email, password, user_type ', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
public function relations()
    {

return array(
        );
    }
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'user_type' => 'User Type',
                        'cpassword' => 'Confirm Password'
        );
    }
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('user_type',$this->user_type,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
        public function beforesave()
        {
            $this->password=md5($this->password);
            return true;
        }


}
```

Comment: Are you looking to check if a user exists based on the inputted email address?

Comment: exactly , but how to check only one field ; is it a good way to create different models for the same table

Comment: You can use scenarios, which are different validation rules based on different scenarios, for example there are different rules for a creating a new record vs updating an existing record. You can read about scenarios here - http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check on the submit with something like:

```
$user = User::model()->find("email = '".trim($model->email)."'");
if (!empty($user)){
     // users exists
} else {
    // user does not exist
}
```

If you really want to use the model, you can setup a rule where email must be unique like so:

```
array('email', 'unique', 'message' => 'Email already in use'),
```

You can then check if the model validates on the submit, specifically the email field. If it doesnt validate the email address exists

Last, you can validate a single model attribute like so:

```
if($model->validate(array('attribute_name')) 
     // valid
}
```

Here is one way of doing the complete action (not the best way but the easiest to understand!)

```
public function actionResetpassword(){
        $model = new User;
        if(isset($_POST['User'])){
            $model->attributes = $_POST['User']; // this is the form as completed by the user
            $user = User::model()->find("email = '".trim($model->email)."'");
            if (!empty($user)){
                // send user their new email
                $this->render("passwordreset"); // user exists, render confirmtion page
            } else {
                // user does not exist, render form and pass $error_message variable with messasge 
                $this->render("resetpassword",array(
                    "model"         =>  $model,
                    "error_message" =>  "No such user found!",
                ));
            }
    } else {
        // this will be rendered if the user has not submitted the form yet
        $this->render("resetpassword",array(
            "model" =>  $model,
        ));
    }       
}
```

Comment: can i check , whether email field is there in the database (like unique) , if not i want to throw error ('message' => 'not a registred email address'))

Comment: one more simple question , if i am using your code $user = User::model()->find("email = '".trim($model->email)."'");
if (!empty($user)){
     // users exists
} else {
    // user does not exist
} and found that user not registerd , how can i push error to corresponding view , ie to yii generated form, $form->error($model, 'email')

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what will happen. So this would most likely go in your controller, after the if(isset($_POST['User'])) { }. So it is querying the database to see if there is a user with an email address equal to the submitted email ($model->email)

Comment: sorry , i dont get you , in controller i am confirming that current user is not having retgistered email , how can i push that error to corresponding view , ie in my view file error msg is showing like this $form->error($model, 'email') , how to assign my error value to this varialble,

Comment: Eskimo, thank you for you valuable response. one more doubt , in your answer you were pushing error to view like this this->render("resetpassword",array(
                    "model"         =>  $model,
                    "error_message" =>  "No such user found!",
                )); But i would like to assign the value of $error_message to $form->error($model, 'email'); so that i can show error in default yii style otherwise i have to write code like <?php echo '<div class='error'>'.$error_message.'<div>'; ?>    , is there any way to do the same. Thank you for your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules() {

    $action = Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
    if($action == 'login'){
        return array(array('username,password', 'required'), array('password', 'length', 'min'=>6, 'max'=>12), array('rememberMe', 'boolean'), array('password', 'authenticate'), array('id, jsid, email, username, password, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'));
    }else{
        return array( array('oldpassword,password1,password2', 'required'), array('password1,password2, oldpassword', 'length', 'min'=>6, 'max'=>12),array('password1', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password2'), array('id, jsid, email, username, password, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),);    
    }
}
```